# Block drop of file into chrome via content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, drag-and-drop, preventdefault, content-script

I am trying to block all drop event via content script in chrome extension. However, the code is getting executed as I can get `console.log` output, but drop of file is not prevented.

`inject.js` file:

```
        console.log("worked?");

        document.addEventListener("ondrop", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
        }, false)

        document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
        }, true);

        document.addEventListener("dragenter", function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
        }, true);

        document.addEventListener("dragleave", function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
        }, true);

        document.addEventListener("drag", function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
        }, true);
```

`manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "BlockDrop",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Block dropping of files .",
  "homepage_url": "http://sample.com?explode_chrome",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "src/bg/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png",
    "default_title": "browser action demo",
    "default_popup": "src/browser_action/browser_action.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "clipboardRead",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "cookies",    
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "src/inject/inject.js"
      ],
      "run_at" : "document_idle"
    }
  ]
}
```